# Unknown operation st

Tags: linux, ubuntu, authentication, root

I ran into the following line while setting up the server in ubuntu. When logging in or accessing as root, the following message is displayed as a warning. Do you know how to get rid of this phenomenon?

```
root@ubuntu:~# sudo -i
Unknown operation st.
root@ubuntu:~#
```

or

```
ssh connection

Last login: Thu Jan 13 12:16:33 2022 from 
Unknown operation st.
root@ubuntu:~#
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. General Linux questions should be posted to [ubuntu.se], [unix.se], or [su] instead.

Comment: thank you. I didn't know such a site existed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's an issue occurs while your shell sourcing.

Try checking your `~/.bashrc` file or any other shell config files(`/etc/profile`, `~/bash_profile`, `~/.profile` etc)

Comment: Thank U. There was an error in the ~/.bashrc shell. I solved!